# Чем intrusive containers отличаются от non-intrusive containers?

Tags: терминология

Чем intrusive  containers отличаются от non-intrusive containers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

non-intrusive контейнеры хранят копию переданных данных. `std::vector<T>`/`std::list<T>` - это не интрузивные контейнеры. Пользователь этих контейнеров не думают, как именно все внутри устроено.

intrusive containers хранят указатель на данные. К примеру, интрузивный список может хранить указатель на начало и все. А указатель на следующий/предыдущий элемент будет хранить сам "элемент".